# Trabajar con dp en Android

Tags: java, android

Mi pregunta creo que debería ser sencilla de responder, pero realmente no sé la respuesta así que allá va:

Estoy tratando de restar a la altura original de un `layout` 50 `dps`. Ahora mismo lo realizo de la siguiente manera:

```
v.getLayoutParams().height = initialHeight -  50;
v.requestLayout();
```

El problema de esto es que está restando a través de la métrica `px`, y me gustaría trabajar con `dp`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Puedes convertir de dp a pixeles de la siguiente forma:

```
// tu cálculo del valor en dp
final float alturaDp = initialHeight - 50;

// Obtener la densidad de pantalla
final float escala = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
// Convertir los dps a pixels, basado en la escala de densidad
alturaPx = (int) (alturaDp * escala + 0.5f);
```

[Fuente original en la documentación oficial disponible en español.](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DensityConsiderations)

Como la respuesta hasta ahora no pareció útil, para que se entienda:

No se puede trabajar con dp en los `LayoutParams`. Internamente, las clases trabajan con pixeles. Entonces la única forma de trabajar con valores en dp es convertirlos a pixeles y luego aplicar los pixeles.

Comment: te respaldo con la misma respuesta de SOen http://stackoverflow.com/a/5255256/4959545

Comment: @Maguz eso no sorprende, lo unico que falta a la respuesta en SOen es la referencia a la fuente en la documentación original.

Comment: sí, y que es más importante ;)

Comment: No sé, a mi me gusta adjuntar la fuente a una documentación original, así espero que más lo leen y más pueden dar respuestas. No quiero ser el filtro a la documentación para todo el mundo. ;)

Answer (score 4):

Otra alternativa, es definir la unidad dp en el archivo *dimens.xml*

```
<dimen name="resta_height">50dp</dimen>
```

y en tu código poner:

```
v.getLayoutParams().height = initialHeight - (int)getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.resta_height);
```

[fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20948892/4959545)

Comment: Como fue la única respuesta que aportó algo nuevo al asunto en la forma adecuada, te lo ganaste. :) ¡Salud!

Comment: Oooh! Gracias :)

Answer (score 3):

**La forma correcta esta esta descrita en el código fuente** de Android:

```
final float scale = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int pixels = (int) (dps * scale + 0.5f);
```

por [Romain Guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298575/romain-guy) quien estuvo trabajando con Android en su inicio.

---

Esto se describe también en la documentación: [**Conversión de unidades dp en unidades de píxeles.**](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#dips-pels)

```
// El umbral gestual expresado en dp
private static final float GESTURE_THRESHOLD_DP = 16.0f;

//Obtener la escala de densidad de la pantalla.
final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
// Convertir el dps en píxeles, basado en la escala de densidad
mGestureThreshold = (int) (GESTURE_THRESHOLD_DP * scale + 0.5f);

// Usar mGestureThreshold como una distancia en píxeles...
```

---

#### Método para convertir dp a pixels.

```
public int getPixelsfromDP(Context ctx, float dps) {
      float scale = ctx.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
      return (int) (dps * scale + 0.5f);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Deberías convertir los 50dp que quieres a píxeles y después restar estos píxeles al height de la vista. La cantidad de píxeles será distinta dependiendo de la densidad de píxeles del dispositivo.

```
Resources r = getResources();
float pixels = TypedValue.applyDimension(
    TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 50, r.getDisplayMetrics());

v.getLayoutParams().height = initialHeight - pixels;
v.requestLayout();
```

Comment: Recomiendo que agregues una descripcion de lo que hace tu codigo

Comment: Por favor, traduce al español en SOes.

Answer (score 0):

Esto te puede ayudar, explica muy bien como funcionan los dp, a mi me ayudó mucho:

[¿Qué son y para qué sirven los DP en Android?](https://tyris-software.com/que-son-y-para-que-sirven-los-dp-en-android/)