# Limitar altura de un Spinner desde Layout

Tags: android, xml, layout

¿Cómo puedo limitar la *altura* de un `Spinner` desde el `layout` donde lo tengo? 
El problema es que en dispositivos con pantallas más pequeña tiene demasiada *altura*, por eso necesito cambiarlo desde el `layout`

`layout`

```
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinnerzodiaco"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/borde_spinner" />
```

Lo que quiero conseguir es esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que sea más pequeño de alto en diferentes `layout`, ya sé como va el tema de `layout`, `layout-large`... Pero no se como puedo modificar la altura del `Spinner`

**EDITO1:**

Haciéndolo así no funciona, no cambia la altura:

`clase`

```
spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerzodiaco);
    try {
        Field popup = Spinner.class.getDeclaredField("mPopup");
        popup.setAccessible(true);

        // Obtiene la variable mPopup y realiza cast a  ListPopupWindow
        android.widget.ListPopupWindow popupWindow = (android.widget.ListPopupWindow) popup.get(spin);

        // Define la altura en dimens.xml
        popupWindow.setHeight(R.dimen.height_spinner);
    }
    catch (NoClassDefFoundError | ClassCastException | NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        Log.e("Exception", e.getMessage());
    }
```

`dimens.xml`

```
<resources>

    ...

    <dimen name="height_spinner">100dp</dimen>

</resources>
```

Si lo hago así, sí:

```
    spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerzodiaco);
    try {
        Field popup = Spinner.class.getDeclaredField("mPopup");
        popup.setAccessible(true);

        // Obtiene la variable mPopup y realiza cast a  ListPopupWindow
        android.widget.ListPopupWindow popupWindow = (android.widget.ListPopupWindow) popup.get(spin);

        // Como ejemplo define la altura a 300 pixeles.
        popupWindow.setHeight(300);
    }
    catch (NoClassDefFoundError | ClassCastException | NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        Log.e("Exception", e.getMessage());
    }
```

Pero necesito tener medidas distintas para cada dispositivo por lo tanto necesito utilizar `dimens.xml`

Comment: Hola amig@ la una forma que conozco es mediante reflection!

Answer (score 1):

has tratado mediante [reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20597584/how-to-limit-the-height-of-spinner-drop-down-view-in-android) :

```
  Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    try {
        Field popup = Spinner.class.getDeclaredField("mPopup");
        popup.setAccessible(true);

        // Obtiene la variable mPopup y realiza cast a  ListPopupWindow
        android.widget.ListPopupWindow popupWindow = (android.widget.ListPopupWindow) popup.get(spinner);

        // Como ejemplo define la altura a 500 pixeles.
        popupWindow.setHeight(500);
    }
    catch (NoClassDefFoundError | ClassCastException | NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        Log.e("Exception", e.getMessage());
    }
```

---

El método anterior funciona con pixeles, si usas dp puedes hacer uso del método que sugiero en esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/51090/95).

```
// Como ejemplo define la altura a 100 dp.
popupWindow.setHeight(getPixelsfromDP(getApplicationContext(), 100));
```

Usando el método:

```
public int getPixelsfromDP(Context ctx, float dps) {
      float scale = ctx.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
      return (int) (dps * scale + 0.5f);
}
```

Comment: Gracias, lo que comentas si funciona pero no como necesito, he actualizado la pregunta, gracias! @Jorgesys

Comment: He visto que necesitas DP, solo usa el método de conversión con eso será suficiente. :)

Comment: No es lo que necesito exactamente, necesito que se obtengan de dimens.xml y no desde la `clase`

Answer (score 0):

Por un lado podés probar con diferentes *layouts* para diferentes tamaños de monitor creando las carpetas **res/layout-xxxx** correspondientes. Pero esto no siempre funciona.

Una mejor opción es usar `RelativeLayout` donde se puede posicionar los elementos respecto de otros en la pantalla.

Creo que la mejor opción es usar un `ConstraintLayout` que te permite definir guías donde podés *enganchar* los elementos fijándoles su lugar en la pantalla sin interesar su tamaño.

Esta última opción tiene una pequeña curva de aprendizaje pero funciona muy bien.

https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html

Comment: Creo que no me explique bien, ya que no comprendo como puedo solucionar mi problema con tu respuesta, añado más información de lo que quiero conseguir, gracias @Juan